# Perform Segue With Identifier for already Instiated View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboard

I'm trying to use a custom segue (at bottom) to present a view controller modally with a blur view. I need to instantiate the view controller with properties before I present the view controller.

Instating the VC works great when I am using pushVC, but when I use perform segue with identifier, I don't see an option to choose an already instantiated VC.

```
    CustomViewController* VC = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customVC"]; 
    [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"blurSegue" sender:self];
```

How can I perform the custom segue and force it to use the view controller I allocated (called VC above)?

https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFBlurSegue

Comment: why do you have to instantiate the view controller before?

Comment: @nburk because its page collection VC and loads its pages based on an array property

Comment: @DyanaJuliana this shouldn't be necessary! check my answer for details :)

Comment: anything still unclear? does my answer help?

Comment: Thanks, this worked !!!!         CustomViewController *customViewController = (CustomViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
 was the key line

Comment: good! glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to instantiate the view controller with properties before I
>   present the view controller.

Why do you have to instantiate `CustomViewController` before triggering the segue. That shouldn't be necessary, if you need access to a *property* of `CustomViewController` *before* it's shown, you can set it in `prepareForSegue`.

Try this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"blurSegue"]) {
        CustomViewController *customViewController = (CustomViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        customViewController.propertyToSet = XXX; // set the property here
    }
}
```

Ah, by the way, instead of

`[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"blurSegue" sender:self];`

just use:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"blurSegue" sender:self];`

Comment: Would           

'CustomViewController* VC = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomerCardCollectionView"];'
            
replace the below:

'CustomViewController* VC = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customVC"];'

Comment: sorry, what are you asking? if you're posting code, please update the answer rather than putting it in the comments! :)